# Bind doesn't work on first KeyPress using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that when a key is pressed or text pasted and cutted from a textarea the amount of characters left will appear but on the first keypress the function doesnt work but on the second one and so in it does. My code is below.

```
$('.Textarea').keypress(function (event) {
    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
        $(this).bind('paste copy cut keypress', function () {
            var CharsLeft = $(this).parent('div').find('.CharsLeft');
            var Chars = $(this).val().length;
            $('.CharsLeft').text(5000 - Chars);
        });

        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            var Value = $(this).val();

            $(this).parent('div').find('.SubMessages').append('<div style="border-top:1px solid #EEE; padding:10px 0;">' + 'You: ' + Value + '</div>');
            $(this).val('');

            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

```
<div class="Message" style="width:100%; text-align:left;">
    <div class="MsgInfo" style="display:block; border-bottom:1px solid #EEE;">
        <span class="InnerMsg">From: Tera</span>
        <span class="InnerMsg">Subject: Welcome To Tera!</span>

        <span class="InnerMsg">When: 2 Hours Ago</span>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="UserMsgContent" style="display:block; padding:10px; line-height:1.5em;">
        <div class="SubMessages">
            <div style="padding:10px 0;">Hello</div>
        </div>
        <textarea style="width:930px;" class="Textarea" placeholder="Reply!" maxlength="5000"></textarea>
        <div style="margin-top:10px;">
            <div class="CharsLeft">5000</div>Characters Left
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us your html?  What is `this`?

Comment: its a textarea one second

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strange behavior.
Binding `keyup keydown` instead of `keypress` fixes it. http://jsfiddle.net/np9w5/1/

Answer (score 5):

Use `keyup` instead as reading the length of the value on `keypress` doesn't give you the accurate length of the text.

When you press the key the `keypress` event fires but your `textarea` has not been updated with the new text until after the key is released. Use `keyup`, similar to the below:

```
$(this).bind('paste copy cut keyup', function() {
    var CharsLeft = $(this).parent('div').find('.CharsLeft');
    var Chars = $(this).val().length;

    $(CharsLeft).text(5000 - Chars);    
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jRzdP/) - Using keyup instead

---

The only thing I changed in the DEMO is the binding selector to `$('.Textarea').bind()` to get it to work in the fiddle as `$(this)` would not work in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).on("keypress", function() {
    var CharsLeft = $(this).parent('div').find('.CharsLeft');
    var Chars = $(this).val().length;

    $(CharsLeft).text(5000 - Chars);    
});
```

try with `.on`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(this).keypress(function() {
    var CharsLeft = $(this).parent('div').find('.CharsLeft');
    var Chars = $(this).val().length;

    $(CharsLeft).text(5000 - Chars);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you wrapping CharsLeft in another $()?

It should be:

```
CharsLeft.text(5000 - Chars);
```

Also, I believe instead of .bind() (which is deprecated) you should be using .on()

Here is the jsFiddle with the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/FzWaD/

Couple more bug fixes included in there as well.